# Bash script to detect the version control system by testing command return status

Tags: bash, shell-script, exit-status

I am working on a bash script that I would like to work for several types of VCS.
I am thinking of testing if a directory is a repo for a system by running a typical info command and checking the return code, success or error.
In pseudo code:

```
if a svn command succeded;
    Then run svn commands
elif a darcs command succeded;
    Then run darcs commands
elif a mercurial command succeded;
    then run hg commands
else 
    something else
fi
```

I can run a command, e.g. 
`darcs show repo` and use `$?` to get its return code.

My question is: is there a neat way to run and return the return code number in one line? for example

```
if [ 0 -eq `darcs show repo`$? ];
```

Or do I have to define a function?

An added requirement is that both stderr and stdout should be printed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If automatically checks the return code:

```
if (darcs show repo); then
  echo "repo exists"
else
  echo "repo does not exist"
fi
```

You could also run the command and use && (logical AND) or || (logical OR) afterwards to check if it succeeded or not:

```
darcs show repo && echo "repo exists"
darcs show repo || echo "repo does not exist"
```

Redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` can be done once with `exec`

```
exec 6>&1
exec 7>&2
exec >/dev/null 2>&1

if (darcs show repo); then
  repo="darcs"
elif (test -d .git); then
  repo="git"
fi

# The user won't see this
echo "You can't see my $repo"

exec 1>&6 6>&-
exec 2>&7 7>&-

# The user will see this
echo "You have $repo installed"
```

The first two `exec` are saving the `stdin` and `stderr` file descriptors, the third redirects both to `/dev/null` (or somewhere other if wished).
The last two `exec` restore the file descriptors again.
Everything in between gets redirected to nowhere.

Append other repo checks like Gilles suggested.

Comment: Nice and clean, however these methods print out messages to the user. I would prefer the script to be silent (I have added this to the question).

Comment: Why are you running these in a subshell? It's unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

As others have already mentioned, `if command` tests whether `command` succeeds. In fact `[ … ]` is an ordinary command, which can be used outside of an `if` or `while` conditional although it's uncommon.

However, for this application, I would test the existence of the characteristic directories. This will be correct in more edge cases. Bash/ksh/zsh/dash version (untested):

```sh
vc=
if [ -d .svn ]; then
  vc=svn
elif [ -d CVS ]; then
  vc=cvs
else
  d=$(pwd -P)
  while [ -n "$d" ]; do
    if [ -d "$d/.bzr" ]; then
      vc=bzr
    elif [ -d "$d/_darcs" ]; then
      vc=darcs
    elif [ -d "$d/.git" ]; then
      vc=git
    elif [ -d "$d/.hg" ]; then
      vc=hg
    fi
    if [ -n "$vc" ]; then break; fi
    d=${d%/*}
  done
fi
if [ -z "$vc" ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "This directory does not seem to be under version control."
  exit 2
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's not very pretty, but it's one way to do it inline:

```
if darcs show repo > /dev/null 2>&1; then <do something>; fi
```

By definition, if tests the exit code of a command, so you don't need to do an explicit comparison, unless you want more than success or failure.  There's probably a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Another succinct option would be:

```
[ -d .svn ] && { svn command 1; svn command 2; }
```