# Is there any way I can fit this into my ~/.bashrc as a function?

Tags: bash, shell-script, function, bashrc

I just discovered this useful bit of code on this [useful-looking website](http://www2.tcl.tk/13817).

```
#!/bin/sh
 exec tclsh "$0" ${1+"$@"}

 proc main {} {
     set lines [lrange [split [read stdin] \n] 0 end-1]
     set count [llength $lines]

     for {set idx_1 0} {$idx_1 < $count} {incr idx_1} {
         set idx_2 [expr {int($count * rand())}]
         set temp [lindex $lines $idx_1]
         lset lines $idx_1 [lindex $lines $idx_2]
         lset lines $idx_2 $temp
     }

     puts [join $lines \n]
 }

 main
```

Unfortunately, I don't like scripts. If I can, I make `bash` functions instead. (I've even gone so far as to completely obfuscate Python scripts in order to fit them into my ~/.bashrc unobtrusively, viz:)

```
dna-ify () {
python -c "exec'eJxdkUFrhDAQhe/5FdNsIQpu9rIspSBtLz330N4EiTq6AY0hiaW7v75j1F1aLwlv3vdmMu4eDpN3h0qbA5pvsJdwHg3bQT022nT51+f7/omx1o0DlGU7hclhWYIe7OgCWKdNINXUQRO1qsp1VjmPGfiLz6BSHk/HDNAsmZ6xWHaQ36zyzXXTgCZ8xEqSrhapmqZUay0Rre7RqAFFBoZUn4sXkbL5RlkrEY+Z8ZSi27mFlxv4zIA+H2jujpDRokn+GFLpUDVEYk+sGcP8BukDDS61VyFckvRfyN1wQ/3aaBsprumMvaUqu97JeJFxMZiIa68res61uhmW1cnqdFw9K0spMRMSvvww2NdQcPzBuhA8gy0iA14I2WBkC7HEFSK9S3NPEgoOj68EerQ55yn7BbL1snM='.decode('base64').decode('zlib')" $@
}
```

So, is there any (and, as the above sample should indicate, I do mean *any*) way I can do that with this bit of code?

Comment: i think you need to get over your script-phobia. maybe stare at a #! line or a ~/bin/ directory listing until it doesn't fill you with revulsion..that kind of desensitisation sometimes works for other phobias.

Comment: as long as it fits in my ~/.bashrc, craig sanders, i can take it with me wherever i go with minimal hassle, and become king of any console with a single `mv` command.

Comment: At most I think you need a function in your .bashrc script that grabs the latest copy of your script collection from your git repository or some such place, and installs it in ~/bin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell `tclsh` to read the script from a different [file descriptor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18899/when-would-you-use-an-additional-file-descriptor), and use a [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) to pass the script.

```
shuffle () {
  tclsh /dev/fd/3 "$@" 3<<'EOF'
proc main {} {
    …
}
main
EOF
}
```

Comment: *that's* the sort of magic i was hoping to start using regularly. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Not what you ask for but line randomization is already implemented in `coreutils`.

Either use `shuf` or `sort -r`.

Try for example:

```
echo {1..10} | tr ' ' '\n' | shuf
```

Example output:

```
8
4
2
7
5
10
6
3
1
9
```

Comment: that's a good point, and i have used `shuf` a lot since reading your answer. thanks.

Comment: Note that `shuf` can do quality random ordering with `--random-source=/dev/random`, while `sort -r` is random enough for most purposes, but cryptographically poor.