# Howto run interactive commands, as another user

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm trying to write a bash script that

- context switches to another user (root, in this case)
- executes a set of commands to *i.* create a user (interactively prompting invoker for username) then *ii.* sets the password on that user
- gets a return value
- then carries on doing stuff, with that return value

I've so far tried an << EOF input (*fig.1*), a function (*fig.2*), and pulling / running a separate script (*fig.3*). However I haven't gotten the results I need.

```
sudo su - << 'EOF'
# do stuff...
EOF
```

*fig.1*

```
function myfunc()
{
    local  myresult='some value'
    echo "$myresult"
}
```

*fig.2*

```
sudo su - -c bash <(curl -fksSL https://<my-script-location>.sh)
```

*fig.3*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> sudo su - << 'EOF'
> # do stuff...
> EOF
> ```

This works, but with a limitation: the script is passed to the shell on its standard input, so you don't get to use the standard input for something else such as reading the name of the user to create.

The simple way of retaining standard input is to pass the shell command as an argument instead.

Note that `sudo su` is redundant — `sudo` runs the specified command as root, and that's the sole purpose of `su` as well. Use `sudo -i` instead of `sudo su -` if you want to run a login shell as root — which is probably unnecessary here — or `sudo sh` to just run a shell as root.

```
sudo sh -c '
  # do stuff...
'
```

This makes it awkward to use a single quote in the shell snippet. You can use `'\''` to put a single quote inside the single-quoted literal. If you want to retain the here document structure, there are several ways. The most straightforward is to pass the here document [on a different descriptor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18899/when-would-you-use-an-additional-file-descriptor). However this requires the `closefrom_override` option to be activated in the sudo configuration, which is not the case by default; by default, `sudo` closes all file descriptors other than stdin, stdout and stderr.

```
sudo -C 3 sh -c '. /dev/fd/3' 3<<'EOF'
# do stuff...
EOF
```

If you want your code to be portable to machines where this option isn't activated, you can read the script from a heredoc and pass it to the shell as an argument.

```
script=$(cat <<'EOF'
# do stuff...
EOF
)
sudo sh -c "$script"
```

Alternatively, if you want the sudoed script to be able to read from the terminal, you can pass the script body on standard input. A limitation of this approach is that it doesn't allow the input of the overall script to be redirected.

```
sudo sh <<'EOF'
exec </dev/tty
# do stuff...
EOF
```

Comment: ***A)*** Running `sudo sh -c '. /dev/fd/3' 3<<'EOF' .. do stuff .. EOF` gives me `sh: 1: .: Can't open /dev/fd/3`. 

***B)*** If I try `strace sudo sh -c '. /dev/fd/3' 3<<'EOF' ... EOF`, I get [this](http://pastebin.com/1JYGGrmJ). 

***C)*** [This post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.unix.solaris/-uBwcopboEw) looks relevant. But it's suggestions didn't work. 

Any hints?

Comment: @Nutritioustim My bad, I'd forgotten that `sudo` closes the file descriptor. See my edited answer. When a program is executed in strace, it loses privileges (the setuid bit is ignored).

Comment: Ok, nice. That gets me a lot further. Whether using i) `sudo sh -c "$script"` or ii) `sudo sh <<'EOF'`, is there a way to pass parameters and get return values, in and out of this method?

Comment: @Nutritioustim Sure: `sh -c '…script…' param0 param1 param2` (i.e. `param` becomes `$1`, etc.). `sudo` returns the return code (value between 0 and 255) from the script.

Comment: schweet. That does the trick - thanks. You can see the results [here](https://github.com/twashing/configurations/blob/master/vm/default/setup-guest.sh). I do have to do emacs-live manually, because it has it's own interactive shell that it runs. And I can't push file descriptor access down to within that script. But this has taken me pretty far.

Comment: @Nutritioustim - you wouldn't have to hack around `sudo` closing the file descriptor if you just used `su` as I recommended.

Comment: @mikeserv I'd really rather not suspend your account, but I thought I was pretty clear last time: stop with the comments

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - if you're asking me to suffer dishonesty and disrespect silently, I am afraid I will not comply. Please visit http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/conversation/more-gilles

Answer (score 1):

Provided that the user invoking `sudo` can allocate a `tty`:

```
Defaults someuser:requiretty
```

ans has been granted permissions to execute the needed commands as root:

```
Cmnd_Alias STUFF = /usr/bin/passwd, /usr/sbin/useradd
someuser ALL = STUFF
```

a script containing `sudo` invocations will be interactive. You could pass the username as a positional argument:

```
sudo useradd $1
sudo passwd $1
```

and check the return status as usual with `$?`.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know the `defaults` command. Apt-get suggests *gnustep-base-runtime*, but that doesn't work. I tried these invocations ([see here](http://pastebin.com/pWhwzk2h)), all erroring out.

Comment: That's supposed to be in the `sudoers` configuration.

Comment: `requiretty` has nothing to do with being *allowed* to allocate a tty, but about sudo enforcing rules to disallow invocation outside of a tty context.

Answer (score -2):

```
su -c '. /dev/fd/4' 4<<\SCRIPT
    ...automated stuff here...
    ....then for interactive...
    exec </dev/tty
SCRIPT
```

Should do it. Tailor this to meet your needs - but it will switch contexts and the shell's return status will be in `$?` when you're through with it.