# Which programs use a file descriptor higher than 2?

Tags: posix, file-descriptors, open-files

Standard file descriptors <= 2 are opened by default.  A program can write to or read from, a file descriptor after 2, without using the `open` system call to obtain such a descriptor.  The program can then advertise in its manual, which file descriptors it is using and how. To make use of this, a POSIX shell can open a file and assign that file to a descriptor with the `exec` built-in. After that, the shell would start the program which will use that descriptor and file.

One reason for doing that would be if the program wants to have more than one output or input file, and does not want to specify them as command line arguments. If there was just one file, you could just redirect a standard file descriptor.

I have never seen a generally available program which would advertise such a thing in its manual.  Does this happen in practice?  Has anybody heard of such a thing?

Yes, I do want to stay within POSIX world - so no bash-only built-ins.  I just want to know if there is such a program, not a shell built-in.

Comment: The bash shell's `read` builtin has an option `-u fd` to read from file descriptor `fd` instead of standard input - does that count?

Comment: Did you look at UCSPI-TCP?  It does exactly what you describe.  But if you say it isn't relevant, I'll just delete my comment.

Comment: @SatoKatsura I did not mean to be rude... I am sorry if it seemed that way.  You were talking about how `open` call returns descriptors.  I know that - but I specifically said in the question, I don't want that situation.

Comment: @steeldriver  good point, thank you - but yes, I would like POSIX only.  I tried your command, yes it works under `bash` but not under `dash`.  Let me update the question.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any program using a FD more than 2 or not, but I thinks [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18899/when-would-you-use-an-additional-file-descriptor) can help you.

Comment: The confusion is because you wrote the question poorly, with "use" instead of "expect to have already open at program startup" or some such.  "use" implies a lot wide range than that, but it's only that that you were asking about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use process substitution with `<(...)` or `>(...)`, bash will open a pipe to the other program on an arbitrary high file descriptor (I think it used to count up from 10, but now it counts down from 63) and pass the name as `/dev/fd/N` on the command line of the first program. This isn't POSIX, but other shells also support it (it's a ksh88 feature).

That's not exactly a feature of the program you're running though, it just sees `/dev/fd/N` and tries to open it like a regular file.

- [The Autoconf manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/File-Descriptors.html) mentions some historic notes:

  > A few ancient systems reserved some file descriptors. By convention, file descriptor 3 was opened to `/dev/tty` when you logged into Eighth Edition (1985) through Tenth Edition Unix (1989). File descriptor 4 had a special use on the Stardent/Kubota Titan (circa 1990), though we don't now remember what it was. Both these systems are obsolete, so it's now safe to treat file descriptors 3 and 4 like any other file descriptors.
- Also while I did a google search for this I found a program called [`runit`](http://smarden.org/runit/svlogd.8.html) that uses file descriptors 4 and 5 for some purpose related to log rotation.
- And quoting from the `svlogd` man page:

  > If `svlogd` is told to process recent log files, (...). `svlogd` also saves any output that the processor writes to file descriptor 5, and makes that output available on file descriptor 4 when running processor on the next log file rotation.

Comment: thank you for mention of `runit` `svlogd` that answers my question.   Everything else that everybody wrote, unfortunately, does not understand the question.  Not sure why, I really tried to make it really clear.

Answer (score 4):

## Yes; plenty.

Sato Katsura mentioned UCSPI, the Unix Client-Server Program Interface.  Programs that adhere to this use standard input, standard output, and standard error as normal.  But the toolset defines further standard open file descriptors beyond that.  There are other toolsets that define similar standard file descriptors beyond the first three.

Some of them are even consistent with one another.  Like `stdaux` and `stdprn` as standard file handles 3 and 4 from the PC-DOS/DR-DOS/MS-DOS world, there's actually a consistent standard usage of file descriptors 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7 in the worlds of some Unix and Linux terminal management, logging management, and UCSPI client softwares.

## UCSPI client-side tools

*6 and 7: standard fromserver and standard toserver*

With UCSPI, people usually mainly remember the server-side protocol, where servers communicate with their standard inputs and outputs.  On the less-remembered client end, however, tools such as `tcpclient` (from Bernstein's UCSPI-TCP), `sslclient` (from Baxter's/Gifford's/Hoffman's UCSPI-SSL), and `tcp-socket-connect` (from the nosh toolset) use further standard file descriptors.  The client programs, that they all chain to, are defined as expecting open file descriptor 6 as reading from the network and open file descriptor 7 as writing to the network.

Bernstein's original ucspi-tcp toolset came with a bunch of nonce TCP tools build around `tcpclient`.  For example:  Here is Bernstein's simple `http@` tool.  (Felix von Leitner published a more complex one a decade and a bit ago.)

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "GET /${2-} HTTP/1.0
Host: ${1-0}:${3-80}
" | tcpclient -RHl0 -- "${1-0}" "${3-80}" sh -c '
  addcr >&7
  exec delcr <&6
' | awk '/^$/ { body=1; next } { if (body) print }'
```

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). *[The gen on the UNIX Client-Server Program Interface](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/UCSPI.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). [`tcp-socket-connect`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/tcp-socket-connect.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- William Baxter (2015).  [`sslclient`](http://superscript.com./ucspi-ssl/sslclient.html).  UCSPI-SSL.  SuperScript.
- [`s6-tcpclient`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6-networking/s6-tcpclient.html).  s6-networking.  Laurent Bercot.

## terminal management tools

*3, 4, and 5: standard ctty, standard PTY master and slave*

Daniel J. Bernstein's original PTY toolset incorporated extra standard file descriptor definitions into the toolset.  File descriptor 3 was the controlling terminal (a convention that Bernstein suggested in his accompanying papers on job control in shells), file descriptor 4 was the master side of a PTY, and file descriptor 5 was its slave side.

The PTY toolset has perhaps the most extreme example of tools that define specific open file descriptor conventions in their manuals.  `ptyspawn`'s manual page discusses file descriptors 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 9.

The nosh toolset's tools for terminal management share some of these.  `pty-get-tty`, for example, passes the master side of the pseudo-terminal that it opens as file descriptor 4; and `pty-run` and `console-terminal-emulator` both expect to receive it there.

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016).  "[Daniel J. Bernstein's `ptyget` toolset](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/djbwares/bernstein-ptyget.html)".  *djbwares*.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2010). *[Daniel J. Bernstein on TTYs in UNIX](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/bernstein-on-ttys/)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). [`pty-get-tty`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/pty-get-tty.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). [`pty-run`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/pty-run.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). [`console-terminal-emulator`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/console-terminal-emulator.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.

## `LISTEN_FDS` protocol

*3 and up: standard listen*

What UCSPI is to passing *connected* sockets, this protocol is to passing *listening* sockets.  (It's in the name.)  The original `inetd` protocol for listening sockets was that they were the standard input of the server process, and this is what Bercot's s6-networking toolset still does, for one.  But in the systemd world, the idea was for server processes to listen on more than one socket simultaneously.  Thus arose this protocol, which defines file descriptors 3 and upwards as being a sequence of *N* open file descriptors, where *N* is the value of the `LISTEN_FDS` environment variable.

So whilst it may not be explicit in their manuals, every server program that incorporates this protocol has a set of "standard listen" file descriptors that it expects.

The manual pages for tools such as `tcp-socket-listen`, which both take and add listening socket file descriptors, do explicitly mention these file descriptors, though.  They also mention the lesser-known `UPSTART_FDS` protocol from the upstart world.

### Further reading

- [`s6-tcpserver6-socketbinder`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6-networking/s6-tcpserver6-socketbinder.html).  s6-networking.  Laurent Bercot.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). [`local-datagram-socket-listen`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/local-datagram-socket-listen.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). [`local-stream-socket-listen`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/local-stream-socket-listen.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [`netlink-datagram-socket-listen`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/netlink-datagram-socket-listen.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). [`tcp-socket-listen`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/tcp-socket-listen.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). [`udp-socket-listen`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/udp-socket-listen.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). [`fifo-listen`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/fifo-listen.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.

## logging tools

*4 and 5: standard rotation data*

As you've already observed, a convention the started with Bernstein's `multilog` was the convention for tools spawned by `multilog` and its successors at log rotation time.  All of these define file descriptors 4 and 5 as a way of passing data from run to run of the rotation filter program.

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). "[Logging](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/daemontools-family.html#Logging)".  *The daemontools family*.  Frequently Given Answers.

## user management tools

*3: standard credentials*

Bernstein's `checkpassword` interface, originally used for validating POP3 server login, defined another suite of tools expecting an extra file descriptor to be open.  Once again, it is file descriptor 3, on which the spawning program is expected to have written, or to be writing, the user account credentials which the password check program validates.  There's a whole subfamily of `checkpassword`-compatible programs nowadays.

### Further reading

- Daniel J. Bernstein.  "[The `checkpassword` interface](http://cr.yp.to/checkpwd/interface.html)".  *Internet mail*.  cr.yp.to.