# A while loop and an here-document - what happens when?

Tags: text-processing, variable, read, here-document, control-flow

I have this while loop and here-document combo which I run in Bash 4.3.48(1) and I don't understand its logic at all.

```sh
while read file; do source ~/unwe/"$file"
done <<-EOF
    x.sh
    y.sh
EOF
```

My question is comprised of these parts:

1. What does the `read` do here (I always use `read` to declare a variable and assign its value **interactively**, but I'm missing what it's supposed to do here).
2. What is the meaning of `while read`? Where does the concept of `while` come in here?
3. If the here-document itself comes **after** the loop, how is it even affected by the loop? I mean, it comes after `done`, and not inside the loop, so what's the actual association between these two structures?
4. Why does this fail?

   ```sh
   while read file; do source ~/unwe/"$file" done <<-EOF
       x.sh
       y.sh
   EOF
   ```

   I mean, `done` is `done`... So why does it matter if `done <<-EOF` is on the same line as the loop? If I recall correctly, I did have a case in which a `for` loop was one-liner and still worked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. The `read` command reads from its standard input stream and assigns what's read to the variable `file` (it's a bit more compicated than that, see [long discussion here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123/understanding-ifs-read-r-line)).  The standard input stream is coming from the here-document redirected into the loop after `done`.  If not given data *from anywhere*, it will read from the terminal, interactively. In this case though, the shell has arranged to connect its input stream to the here-document.
2. `while read` will cause the loop to iterate until the `read` command returns a non-zero exit status.  This will happen if there are any errors, or (most commonly) when there is no more data to be read (its input stream is in an end-of-file state).

   The convention is that any utility that wishes to signal an error or "false" or "no" to the calling shell does so by returning a non-zero exit status.  A zero exit status signals "true" or "yes" or "no error". This status, would you wish to inspect it, is available in `$?` (only from the last executed utility).  The exit status may be used in `if` statements and `while` loops or anywhere where a test is required.  For example

   ```
   if grep -q 'pattern' file; then ...; fi
   ```
3. A here-document is [a form of redirection](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07).  In this case, it's a redirection into the loop.  Anything inside the loop could read from it but in this case it's only the `read` command that does.  Do read up on here-documents.  If the input was coming from an ordinary file, the last line would have been

   ```
   done <filename
   ```

   Seeing the loop as one single command may make this more intuitive:

   ```
   while ...; do ...; done <filename
   ```

   which is one case of

   ```
   somecommand <filename
   ```

   Some shells also supports "here-strings" with `<<<"string"`:

   ```
   cat <<<"This is the here-string"
   ```

   [DavidFoerster points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/422557/a-while-loop-and-an-here-document-what-happens-when/422560?noredirect=1#comment760648_422560) that if any of the two scripts `x.sh` and `y.sh` reads from standard input, without explicitly being given data to read from a file or from elsewhere, the data read will actually come from the here-document.

   With a `x.sh` that contains only `read a`, this would make the variable `a` contain the string `y.sh`, and the `y.sh` script would never run. This is due to the fact that the standard input is redirected for *all* commands in the `while` loop (and also "inherited" by any invoked script or command) and the second line is "consumed" by `x.sh` before the `while` loop's `read` can read it.

   If this behaviour is unwanted, it can be avoided, [but it's a bit tricky](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18899/when-would-you-use-an-additional-file-descriptor).
4. It fails because there is no `;` or newline before `done`.  Without `;` or newline before `done`, the word `done` will be taken as an argument of `source`, and the loop will additionally not be properly closed (this is a syntax error).

   It is almost true that any `;` may be replaced by a newline (at least when it's a command delimiter). It signals the end of a command, as does `|`, `&`, `&&` and `||` (and probably others that I have forgotten).

Comment: +1 and one nitpick: "Anything inside the loop could read from it but in this case it's only the `read` command that does." – Any or all of the sourced shell scripts (and their recursively invoked commands) can read from standard input and change the the loop invocations.

Comment: @DavidFoerster That is correct. I was a bit blind to what the code actually did. I will add something about this.. soon.

Comment: Avoiding trouble with other things reading from stdin is fairly easy in this case; just pass the here-document in on unit 3 instead of stdin (`... done 3<<-EOF`) and have the `read` command read from unit 3 (`while read file <&3; do ...`).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yes it's easy, depending on your level of expertise and confidence. After more than 25 years at the command prompt, I still can only think of a handful of times (if that) that I've had to do file descriptor juggling like that, and I will always have to look it up :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are in effect creating an object as a doc and then redirecting it back into a while loop that reads it line by line until there are no lines left, executing a source command on that line.

Another way to execute it is as follows:

Assuming that the lines

```
x.sh
y.sh
```

were in a file called:

```
input.txt
```

We could execute

```
cat input.txt | while read file
   do source ~/unwe/"$file"
done
```

The here doc makes things more interactive but the above example may allow you to understand it better.

Comment: This other way is not equivalent to the original because the sourcing may happen in a subshell.