# How to pipe fd 3 to consumer instead of fd1 / fd2

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, file-descriptors, node.js

I was hoping to do something like this:

```
echo 'foo' >&3  3|  cat
```

Basically, I want to write '`foo`' to `3`, and then only pipe the data in `3` to `cat`. But the above doesn't work, I get:

```
bash: 3: Bad file descriptor
```

Does anyone understand what I am trying to do?

With Node.js, I have working example, here:
https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/0ad178f4512bbf956e54dd08f2412883

In that Node.js gist, which seems reliable, at the command line we do:

```bsh
node foo.js 3> some-file.sh
```

and in the node process we are writing to the `3` file descriptor.

But I am wondering how to do it with pipes instead of redirection.

Something like this:

```bsh
node foo.js 3|  cat
```

Comment: "I am wondering how to do it with pipes instead of redirection" There's no way with anonymous pipes - these default to stdout.  But probably you could make a named pipe with `mkfifo` and wire two commands together in subshells. Something like this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18903/85039

Answer (score 4):

```sh
{ echo 'hello on fd3' >&3; } 3>&1 | cat
```

Here, `echo` writes to standard output, but we redirect it to file descriptor 3 (this corresponds to the writing to `w` that you do in your Node application).  We then output the stream on file descriptor 3 to standard output to be able to send it over the pipe to `cat`.

To also discard the standard output:

```sh
{ echo 'hello on fd1'; echo 'hello on fd3' >&3; } 3>&1 1>/dev/null | cat
```

The first `echo` writes to standard output, and the second writes, via a redirection as in the first example, to file descriptor 3.  File descriptor 3 is then sent to standard output (to be able to pipe it) while standard output is discarded.

Note that the `1` in `1>/dev/null` is not actually needed and just added here for clarity.

Both pipelines output `hello on fd3` only.

For your Node application:

```sh
node foo.js 3>&1 | cat
```

or, to also discard standard output,

```sh
node foo.js 3>&1 1>/dev/null | cat
```

or, to send standard output to standard error (the terminal by default),

```sh
node foo.js 3>&1 1>&2 | cat
```

Comment: I don't want to mix 1 and 3. In short, I am looking to use 1 for metadata, 2 for errors, 3 for data.

Comment: @AlexanderMills Sure. But to pipe fd 3, you have to redirect it to standard output. There is no way around that.

Comment: I see what you are saying, so maybe process substitution is a less verbose alternative? idk

Comment: @AlexanderMills You question only ever asks about how to send the single stream on fd 3 to `cat`. It never shows what you want to do with standard output or standard error.

Comment: Well by default both stdout and stderr are going to the terminal, right, that's fine. A simple use case is to not be like curl. curl writes it's metadata to stderr which is so annoying and dumb. I want to silence the metatdata but still see errors.

Comment: @AlexanderMills By default, with only a `3>&1` redirection, you would mingle the standard output with the output to fd 3, and standard error would go to the terminal. If you want to pipe fd 3 and send standard output to the terminal, use `3>&1 1>&2 | cat` (this would mingle standard output and error on the terminal).

Comment: nice, that makes sense, ty

Comment: and I suppose the ordering of the redirection commands matters?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Most definitely, yes. Swapping them would intermingle fd 3 and standard output (and nothing would actually be piped to `cat`).

Answer (score 4):

You can do it without process substitutions and without mixing fd 1 and 3 or fd 1 and 2:

```
producer(){ echo to_out; echo >&2 to_err; echo >&3 to_fd3; }
consumer(){ sed "s/^/consumer $@: /" >/dev/tty; }

{ producer 3>&1 >&4 | consumer 3; } 4>&1 | consumer 1
to_err
consumer 1: to_out
consumer 3: to_fd3

{ producer 3>&1 >&4 | consumer 3; } 4>&1
to_out
to_err
consumer 3: to_fd3
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite a pipe via process-substitution:

```
# cmd 3> >(cat)
```

Or, if you are ok to mix the output of fd3 and stdout,

```
# cmd 3>&1 | cat
```

Comment: I believe there is a way to avoid mixing stdout in the last example, probably via another file descriptor, but that gets complex.

Comment: sadly this doesn't work, and I don't know why, it says that file descriptor 3 is not writable, it's not open by using the process substitution for some reason

Comment: see my answer, I wish this were easier, I think if it were commonplace to write metadata to 1, errors to 2, and data to 3, the software world would be better.

Comment: @AlexanderMills I don't see why that wouldn't work. Maybe your app expects a __seekable__ or __readable__ file descriptor as its fd 3? Please add a complete reproducible testcase to your Q. I don't see how your answer is different (other than trying to open a process subst pipe as rw -- which may only work on *bsd and isn't needed in your example)  -- it could be written in a single line as `{ echo a >&3; } 3> >(cat >temp.sh)`

Comment: @AlexanderMills notice that on FreeBSD, you need to mount `fdescfs` in order to use `/dev/fd/3` and larger. Please add complete OS details to your Q.

Answer (score 0):

So with bash, this does work:

```
exec 3<> >(cat > temp.sh)
echo a >&3 # write to it
exec 3>&- # close fd 3.
```

but I am wondering if there is a less verbose way to do it. And to do without process substitution, instead of using pipes.

Comment: Makes sense. You need to open the fd first.