# Is there a way to bypass the pipe in a shell script or function?

Tags: shell-script, shell, zsh, ps

I would like to write a small wrapper around `ps` so that no matter what the options are or if I grep the result,  I could have the first line of the output of `ps` which tells me what the columns are.
For example, the output of `ps_wrapper -aux | grep thing` would be something like:

```
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
name       33925  1.0  0.0   9972  5528 pts/0    Ss   19:34   0:00 /bin/thing
```

I tried to see if `tee` could be of use, and tried something like

```bsh
function ps_wrapper {
    tmpfile=$(mktemp)
    ps $@ > $tmpfile
    head -n 1 $tmpfile >> /dev/stdout
    cat $tmpfile
}
```

but I soon realized that of course, even if I wrote "manually" to `/dev/stdout`, it would still be piped to `grep`.

I want to print the first line of the actual command I am running because the columns printed by `ps` can change depending on which options are used.

I am using zsh but I don't mind using another tool if there is one more appropriate.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's impossible to generically “bypass the pipe”, as in, send output to wherever the output would go if there wasn't a pipe. However, it's possible to bypass the pipe in the sense of redirecting output to another place of your choice, such as the terminal. The special file `/dev/tty` always represents the current terminal.

```
function ps_wrapper {
    tmpfile=$(mktemp)
    ps "$@" > $tmpfile
    head -n 1 $tmpfile >/dev/tty
    cat $tmpfile
    rm $tmpfile
}
```

It's also possible to bypass the pipe if you “save” the original location and pass it down [via a file descriptor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18899/when-would-you-use-an-additional-file-descriptor/18904#18904). But you can't do that from the `ps_wrapper` function.

```
function ps_wrapper {
    tmpfile=$(mktemp)
    ps "$@" > $tmpfile
    head -n 1 $tmpfile >&3
    cat $tmpfile
    rm $tmpfile
}
{ ps_wrapper … | grep …; } 3>&1
```

There are many ways to avoid creating a temporary file. I'll mention a few. Unless otherwise indicated, the solutions in this answer work in bash if you [add double quotes around variable and command substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).

If you're willing to change the way you call the function, you can call `head` and `grep` successively on the right-hand side of the pipe. `head` will read and print the first line, and leave the rest for its successor to consume.

```
ps … | { head -n 1; grep …; }
```

You can a [process substitution](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Process-Substitution) with either `tee` or [zsh's built-in `tee`-like feature (`multios`)](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Multios) to duplicate the output, sending one stream to `head -n 1` and another to the command of your choice. However, if you just pipe each stream to a command, there'll be a race between the two, and if `head` isn't quick enough, the first line may not end up at the top. It'll probably often work because `head` is pretty quick, but there's no guarantee, for example if `grep` is in the disk cache but `head` isn't.

```
ps | tee >(head -n 1 >/dev/tty) | grep …
ps >(head -n 1 >/dev/tty) | grep …         # zsh only, only if multios is not disabled
```

You can use awk to display the first line, then pass the rest through.

```
function ps_wrapper {
  ps "$@" | awk 'NR == 1 {print >"/dev/tty"} NR != 1 {print}'
}
```

Explanations:

- awk processes the input line by line.
- *CONDITION* { *CODE* } executes *CODE* on the lines that fulfill *CONDITION*.
- `NR` is the line number.
- Redirection in awk works not exactly like the shell, but close enough here.
- `print` with no argument prints the input line.

Another approach would be to build the filter functionality into a single command. Pick a string that won't appear in the arguments to `ps` to use as a separator, for example `|`.

```
function pipe_preserving_first_line {
  local lhs
  lhs=()
  while [[ $1 != '|' ]]; do
    lhs+=($1)
    shift
  done
  shift
  "${lhs[@]}" | {
    head -n 1;
    "$@"
  }
}
pipe_preserving_first_line ps u \| grep foo
```

Instead of using grep, you can use `ps`'s matching facilities such as `-C` to match a process by its command name.

```
ps uww -C mycommand
```

Instead of using grep, you can use `pgrep`'s matching facilities.

```
ps -p $(pgrep -d, mycommand)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough answer. I quickly tested the solution which used `/dev/tty` and it seems to work exactly like I wanted; I'll take the time to study more closely the other approaches to find the one which suits my needs the most. Thank you again.